# ObjectParameter.Value InvalidCastException for null value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In SQL  procedure returs null for out parametr but in C# in if whene I try to check if id==null I got   System.InvalidCastException
This error drives me crazy becose in debuge mode id==null is TRUE but anyway System.InvalidCastException is throwen

```
 var outObj = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("ID",typeof(int?));
            db.spGetSOFolderID(soid, branchId, outObj, kindID);
            int? id = null;
            id =(int?)outObj.Value;
  if (id==null) ///here error
            return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALY found solution.

```
 var outObj = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("FolderID", typeof(int?));
            db.spGetSOFolderID(soid, branchId, outObj, kindID);
            if (outObj.Value is DBNull)
                return null;
            int? id = (int?)outObj.Value;
```

So really the problem was in `int? id = (int?)outObj.Value;` But why I got InvalidCastException  erro on `if(id==)`  is still secret for me.

Comment: I think it might be because of compiler optimization so the cast and check was done together in if.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the origin of the problem is this line.

```
  db.spGetSOFolderID(soid, branchId, outObj, kindID);
```

because, the rest of the code seems to fonction correctly.

Comment: function works correctly an out parammeter is null in this case

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer.